# shmget() run fail in Netbeans

Tags: c++

I want to do shared memory, and I just use

```
int shmid= shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 10000, IPC_CREAT|0666);
```

and it directly run fail, I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Does it work from command line? And, what is the return value in `shmid`?

Comment: @Azeem Yes, it is . and nothing return.Directly run fail

Comment: Does it run with or without root privileges from the command line? Is NetBeans running as root?

Comment: @Azeem What does root mean?

Comment: How do you compile and run the program from the terminal? Commands?

Comment: @Azeem I made the switch from windows to linux and it worked.

Comment: That's great! Cheers! I thought you _were_ on a Linux machine. BTW, how were you compiling it on Windows?

Comment: Relevant read: [Shared Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory). Observe the sections on Linux, Windows and cross-platform support.